# MySQL SELECT query ignores indexes on one table, uses them on another

Tags: mysql, indexing

After watching the excellent "How to Design Indexes, Really" video by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin), I decided to create some indexes. However, I have encountered some unexplained behavior when working with indexes.

I have 2 test tables - "owl_oners" and "puma_owners".
When I run this EXPLAIN query on "puma_oners"
`EXPLAIN SELECT owner_id FROM puma_owners ORDER by name LIMIT 1;`
I receive this result:
[image]

But when I run an identical query on "owl_owners":
`EXPLAIN SELECT owner_id FROM owl_owners ORDER by name LIMIT 1;`
I get a different result:
[image]

Why am I getting different results?
Both tables are practically identical:
[image]

[image]

Both tables have 2 columns "name" and "owner_id", the main difference is that in "owl_owners" the field "name" is much larger.
Here is sample content from "puma_owners":
[image]
In the "owl_owners" it's the same, only there are a lot more "b" characters appended at the end of the name - up to 32k.

Both databases have the same 4 indexes, covering all the possibilities.
In the "owl_owners" table I have limited "name" in the indexes to 750 first characters, even though the values are unique even within 10 first characters.

Why isn't the query on the "owl_owners" table using the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the index allows it to not have to sort the results.  If the index does not encompass the entire column, it will still have to sort, so it doesn't bother using the index, even though that would produce results in a mostly sorted order.

If in fact the name is some kind of composite value, and the beginning part is unique, consider having that in a separate column and indexing and ordering by that?

Comment: Do you meant that it is completely pointless to create indexes if they don't include the full width of the column?

Comment: no, but if you are selecting all records and just using the index to optimize `order by`, they are pointless.  the index is still useful if you are doing `where name=?`

Answer (score 1):

You have found an example of why "index prefix" (`name(750)`) is often useless.

Another tip:  When you have `INDEX(a, b)`, there is almost never any use for also having `INDEX(a)`.  (There are 3 useless indexes in each table.)

More tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql